# how to enable php4 only, no php5

Tags: php, lamp

I have a LAMP server with Ubuntu 9.10, Apache 2, Mysql 5 and PHP5.   I want to disable PHP5 and use only PHP4.  Can anyone explain how to do this?

I'm doing this because I need to simulate an environment similar to a legacy lamp server.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no PHP4 package in Ubuntu 9.10.

I guess you could download the PHP4 source from http://www.php.net/releases/ and compile it yourself.

Myself I would download the still supported Ubuntu 6.06, which does have PHP4 packages, and install it in a virtual machine. That way I could play around with old stuff without causing conflicts with my current system. You can find Ubuntu 6.06 iso files at http://releases.ubuntu.com/6.06/

Answer (score 0):

You could add the repos for an older version and install the PHP4 package, similar to what andol says.

Comment: How sure are you about that working in this case?
(Myself I'm somewhat sceptic, considering the packages involved, the age of them, etc.)